# Batch inserts with JDBC and Unique constraint

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have a working method in Java that inserts many rows as a batch.

The issue I'm facing is that I have a unique constraint on my table and if there are some rows that are already in the table the method does not insert the ones that do not belong in the database. Instead it throws the following exception

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO .... was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
```

Is there anything I can do to make the method insert the ones that are not already in table and not abort like it's doing now?

Comment: Can you perhaps change the SQL in the command from a plain insert to an insert with a where condition that checks that a record with the given field value doesn't exist?

Comment: that could work, I have to make the sql statement to see how well it would work

Comment: unfortunately postgresql does not support merge or upsert yet

Comment: @AlexanderKudrevatykh I think version 9.5 will

Comment: You appear to want a bulk upset operation. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17267417/398670

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this stuff through before insert trigger on that table.

Comment: I was doing that before but with thousands of rows it slows down. There are no alternatives?

Comment: Based upon which field or combination of fields do you decide if that row is already their in db?
Before your batch insert, you can get those through a prepared statement in java, then compare (and whatever logic you need), and send only those rows through which won't fail.

Comment: Only if you `LOCK` the table first.